# Set maximum withdrawal limit logic

Tags: java

I am developing a sample banking application where my bank can give loan from different people's account to borrower.
Bank has a maximum cap how much it can take from each person's account to fulfil the required amount.

I wrote this code where I am able to get the list of person which can give the loan and it works fine.
Now I need to set a limit of 500$ maximum that I can withdraw from each person's savings account.

And I am not able to get that piece of code working.

The current implementation is as follows where there is no maximum withdrawal limit from a persons account.

```
public static List<Person> persons(final List<Person> person, final Long amount) {
        List<Person> results = new ArrayList<>();
        Long balance = amount;
        for (Person p : person) {
            if (p.getAvailableAmount().compareTo(balance) < 0) {
                results.add(p);
                balance = balance - p.getAvailableAmount();
            }
            else if (p.getAvailableAmount().compareTo(balance) > 0) {
                p.setAvailableAmount(p.getAvailableAmount() - (p.getAvailableAmount() - balance));
                results.add(p);
                break;
            }
            else {
                results.add(p);
                break;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Define `MAX_WITHDRAWL_TILL_NOW` as a static variable and use that to check if you have already crossed the limit or not

Comment: yes but how to check, that is what I am struggling with. The condition basically

Comment: Sorry not static, instance variables

Comment: Please refrain from vandalising this question further. When you ask a question here, you donate your question to the commons, so that it can be used in perpetuity for the Stack Overflow Q&A. The licensing terms are in the site footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution should be something like below i.e. creating a new method in Person class for providing the limited amount.

**Solution.java**

```
public class Solution {
    public static List<Person> persons(final List<Person> person, Long amount) {
        List<Person> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Person p : person){
            Long available = p.getLimitedAvailableAmount();
            if(amount <= available){
                p.setAvailableAmount(p.getAvailableAmount() + (available-amount));
                results.add(p);
                break;
            }
            amount = available;
            results.add(p);
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

**Person.java**

```
class Person{
    private static final long LIMIT = 500;

    Long availableAmount;


    public Long getAvailableAmount() {
        return availableAmount;
    }

    public Long getLimitedAvailableAmount() {
        long limited = (availableAmount > LIMIT) ? LIMIT : availableAmount;
        availableAmount -= limited;
        return  limited;
    }

    public void setAvailableAmount(Long availableAmount) {
        this.availableAmount = availableAmount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `int MAX_WITHDRAWL_TILL_NOW = 500;` inside your person on class level, and you can tweak the code as below to check for the condition: -

```
public static List<Person> persons(final List<Person> person, final Long amount) {
    List<Person> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Long balance = amount;
    for (Person p : person) {
        if (p.MAX_WITHDRAWL_TILL_NOW > 500) {
            if (p.getAvailableAmount().compareTo(balance) < 0) {
                results.add(p);
                balance = balance - p.getAvailableAmount();
            }
            else if (p.getAvailableAmount().compareTo(balance) > 0) {
                p.setAvailableAmount(p.getAvailableAmount() - (p.getAvailableAmount() - balance));
                results.add(p);
                break;
            }
            else {
                    results.add(p);
                    break;
            }
    }
 }
    return results;
}
```

Please add custom code to update `MAX_WITHDRAWL_TILL_NOW` as per your requirement.

Having instance variables can help you manage variables on object level for each instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be as below.

Step 1: put `Max_capping` in the `configuration` file.
Step 2: add one field in `Person class` (currentLentAmount something like this) that tells you out of that `Max_capping` how much is already consumed by the bank.
Step 3: then you can consider that field in the logic you have shared.